# About the post "How to use “Filter” matlab function to apply channel to signal?"

Tags: digital-communications

I would like to add my question to the post [How to use “Filter” matlab function to apply channel to signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62033/how-to-use-filter-matlab-function-to-apply-channel-to-signal/62082?noredirect=1#comment125179_62082), but I don't have permission to  do that.

The user @Anna Koroleva discussed with @Enginner the Matlab function "rayleighchan". Usually, I am using outputs of the function as `filter(h,s)` but there they discussed that it is possible to fill outputs in the matrix.

How to fill `PathGains` in the matrix? Could you please give me an example of how to do it?

EDIT 1:

I have wrote a script to simulate user @Engineer suggestion :

```
N=4; Nr=2; Nt=2
h = rayleighchan(Ts, Fd, tau, pdb);
chan = zeros(N,Nr, Nt);
ofdm_chan = zeros(N,Nr, Nt);
for k=1:N
    chan(:,k) = filter(h,ones(N,1));
end
```

But it doesn't work. Should I implement in another way?

Comment: Calling ```rayleighchan``` gives you a randomly generated channel coefficient, so for a $M \times N$ channel matrix, you could call ```rayleighchan``` $M*N$ times

Comment: First, you don't need to use ```rayleighchan```. You could just generate the random variables yourself. Second, why do you use ```filter```? What is your system model?

Comment: @Engineer I was using the same system as in linked post. MIMO

Comment: @Engineer I was thinking It is interesting post and would like to try to implement such things.